# EC2: Rails Nginx installation

Tags: nginx

I am running into an issue where I cannot find the sites-available folder under
/etc/nginx/

Install nginx from source.

nginx -v : nginx version: nginx/1.0.14

Folders under /etc/nginx :
**conf.d**  fastcgi_params  koi-utf  koi-win  mime.types  nginx.conf  scgi_params  uwsgi_params  win-utf

nginx default.conf located under conf.d folder. Rest of the above are all stand alone files.

I want nginx to show my rails app but I cannot find sites-available folder to add that configuration.

Comment: Why don't you simply create one?

Comment: I can definitely do that but not sure if it would affect the configuration in any way.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your title.  Everyone can tell when your question has a selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"site-available" etc is just a specific configuration arrangement to manage files from Ubuntu and is not part of Nginx.

If you want to use such an arrangement, and not using the Ubuntu package manager to install Nginx, you need to create the folder yourself.

You might have seen examples with this on the web simply because the people writing these use Ubuntu and just assume everybody else is. As said,it makes no difference to Nginx and is just a convenience thing. I.E., a place to put the config files for individual domains. You can call it whatever you want or just dump the individual files in /etc/nginx/ if you want.

I use a completely different folder system for instance and what this happens to be, if any, is of no relevance to the operation of Nginx.

BTW. conf.d is a valid place put individual conf files and is actually the default place for this. Site-available etc type configurations are changing from this.

Comment: Thanks Dayo. I had installed nginx from source and I think that might be a reason for a different folder structure.

I ended up installing through a package, sudo aptitude install nginx, I think. As most of the tutorials used the folder structure with sites-available used to store conf files, I wanted to follow that route.

Comment: You can use that folder structure or any other if you want. Just create the folder as needed. Please accept the answer if the query is now closed.

Comment: Hi. You need to tick the checkmark next to the answer to accept it and close the query. Cheers

Comment: @Dayo where is you nginx is installed ? is it in `/etc/nginx` or `/opt/nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this at the end of your Nginx conf file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf before the last closing bracket:

```
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Create the site-enabled folder and conf files as needed.